# Sql Select direclty from a DataReader

Tags: c#, sql, .net, dataset, datareader

I developed a C# application which needs to read data from a database.

If I run this application on the server where the database is stored, it's fast, but, if I run this application by network, the SQL query is slow.

I would like to modify my program in order to store a first request answered in application memory, and secondly be able to do another SQL query on memory (in order to don't use network transfer).

Is there any possibilities to do SQL query in a datareader ?

Or maybe I need to use a Dataset ?

Comment: Probably you need to look at something called Linq

Comment: Let's clarify a little bit the things. What's taking too long in C# code: to execute query or to execute query and show the data returned by query?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Look into "LINQ to Objects", which allows you to do in-memory queries. You don't need to resort to `DataSet`, which is pretty old technology.

Comment: Just how do you expect to do another SQL query in memory?   And how would that avoid a network transfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. ADO.NET gives you that option. Load a `DataTable` with your data or a `DataSet` if you have more then one table. You can store this locally in memory and you can query your `DataTable` and sort and filter rows almost like real Sql database. You can issue Inserts/Updates/Deletes on specific rows and you may want to refresh data periodically. YOu will be limited only by amount of memory on the machine which stores the data in memory.

Comment: Thankd for the answer, i have only one table. So maybe dataset is better no ? Whih method i need to use on the dataset to querying ?

Comment: You query DataTable. YOu don't need whole dataset if only one table exists. DataSet gives you more stuff, such as, you can even have relationships between tables. YOu can use different `DataView`s to sort and filter data. It is amazing what you can do with data in disconnected state using ADO.NET

Comment: Good Answer, i made my sql request and store it in a DataTable. Next, i used Linq To DataSet in order to qurying my DataTable ! Thanks :)